# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't recognize my gtx 1050ti graphic card

Tags: nvidia, graphics

I have a dual boot pc (win 10 and Ubuntu 16.04).
I was going to install caffe on my Ubuntu according to instructions I found in web, before installing caffe I have to install nvidia drivers and cuda.
so I followed the instruction on the below link to install nvidia driver

https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus

but when I run

```
$ lspci -vnn | grep VGA
```

the output do not show my graphic card model,it is:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1c82] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

I think Ubuntu does not recognize my graphic card, and I don't know how to fix it.
Also I should say I'm a beginner in linux.

I will be so grateful if anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think thats an issue. Your output matches what I see on my Ubuntu 16.04 with GTX 1060. I have it setup to use cuDNN and CUDA with Tensorflow and it works well.

Here is my output for `lspci -vnn | grep VGA`:

```
65:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1c03] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 VGA controller])
```

Once you have CUDA setup you could run one of the sample programs, such as deviceQuery:

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#device-query

This should give you more details on the specific GPU model, along with confirming CUDA is working properly.